# Python: Any way to webscrape and detect changes in a single-page application?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, single-page-application

So I'm trying to webscrape and check for a specific change in a website, and the website has a search bar in which I need to enter something into to get into the *specific* page in which I want to webscrape. The problem is, the website is a single-page application where the URL does not change after the page is refreshed with new results. I have tried using `requests` but it is not use as it is dependant on the URL...

Is there a method in `requests`, or a python library, that can bypass this issue and allow me to move forward with my idea?

Comment: Assuming the url does not change after you send the search term, it looks like the web page is doing HTTP call, gets new data back and re render parts of the page. Use Chrome dev tools (Network - XHR) in order to see how does  the page gets its new data. Maybe this is the information you need.

Comment: some pages may render different full page based on data send in request (as POST or as GET) so `requests` may also send this data and get new page. But mostly page uses `JavaScript` to send data, get response and update content in page. But it has to use some differen url to get this data and you can find it with DevTool in Chrome/Firefox. And then you can use `requests` with this url. Mostly JavaScript sends data in JSON format which you can easily convert to Python's dictionary and you don't have to scrape it.

Comment: @CosmicCat Was my answer helpful? I can extend if you'd like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is, try opening the page with developer console. Check what kind of requests the SPA is sending (the XHR requests is what interests you)  when you enter your data. The url address the payload format etc. Then mimic the webpage. Create a `session` object with `requests`, get the page (probably this is not mandatory but it won't hurt so why not) and then send the payload to the right address, you will receive your data. Probably it won't be HTML and more some kind of JSON data but that is even better because it is easier to work with later on. If you do need to have the HTML version there are bindings in python to libraries such as `PhantomJS`. You can use them to render the page and then check for existence of specific elements. Also you can use `selenium` it is library that allows you to control your browser. You can even watch it work. It uses your existing browser so it can handle any kind of webpage SPA or other. It all depends on your needs. If your after the pure data I would go with my first solution if you would like to mimic a user then `selenium` is by far the simplest.

Below example usage of selenium, exert from their website.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# go to the google home page
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# the page is ajaxy so the title is originally this:
print driver.title

# find the element that's name attribute is q (the google search box)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("q")

# type in the search
inputElement.send_keys("cheese!")

# submit the form (although google automatically searches now without submitting)
inputElement.submit()

try:
    # we have to wait for the page to refresh, the last thing that seems to be updated is the title
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("cheese!"))

    # You should see "cheese! - Google Search"
    print driver.title

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: So I copied down this code and ran it on the single page application with the key that I wanted and it worked, right after "WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("text"))' I tried calling requests.get() on the URL but it still referred returned the XML of the pre-refreshed website (expected)....Truth is, despite your thorough answer, Im very new to all this, so I had trouble understanding what exactly it is that you're saying :/

Comment: @CosmicCat You misunderstood. Selenium works as a standalone you cannot mix it up with requests. Those are to different approaches. Either use selenium or requests. `requests` creates its own `Session` object. You asked for a python library `Selenium` is the answer now you need a little time to learn it :)
This line `EC.title_contains("cheese!")` waits for a specific title to show up but you can wait for any kind of HTML element, attribute etc.

Comment: @CosmicCat If my answer was helpful please mark it as correct or/and upvote it. If you'd like to see implementation of your problem ask another question specifically about selenium with details about the site etc. and you will receive a working example. You question was about python library I think my answers on this subject is sufficient :)

Comment: Is there any way to print my selenium webpage result after refreshing as JSON or XML into my python console?

Comment: @CosmicCat the source code for the page is available under `driver.page_source`